# Single View with Dynamic template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've got modules that if enabled/disabled would require a different arrangement of tables and iframes on the frontend webpage. In order to do this I set up a function to check which modules are enabled/disabled and assigned a number to each 'set' and will be created separate templates for each "set1.html", "set2.html", "set3.html", etc...

I'd like to utilize one single view where I can pass the set number from from function I created but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
def homeset(request):
   return render(request, 'app/set1.html', {})
```

Looking to figure out some way to make the "1" the return of the function I created to determine which set# to load as template and would prefer to not have to create a view for every single template needed.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. The template parameter there is just a string, you can construct it any way you like including using a variable returned from another function.

Comment: Sorry. Part of being a Python/Django newbie I have a hard time trying to describe my issue. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just taking a stab at this, do you have a problem with setting the template name before rendering?

```
def homeset(request):
    # define 'my_set'
    # define num
    ...
    my_template_name = None         
    if num in my_set:
        my_template_name = 'app/set{}.html'.format(num)
    return render(request, my_template_name)
```

Comment: That was it! I figured it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Scott Skiles answered your question, but an alternative way is to use a single base template and the ["include" templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

You can pass the set number to the template and use the "if" templatetag" to include the content from appropriate template(s) for each set number.

```
{% if set_num == 1 %}
    {% include "foo/bar.html" %}
{% elif set_num == 2 %}
    {% include "foo/two.html" %}
{% endif %}
```